# List parameters and their values while inside a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-11g-r2, audit

I have a number of Oracle stored procedures whose activity I want to be able to audit, so I am having them `INSERT` some data into an auditing table.

It would be swell if I could list the variables and their values as well.

Is it possible to get this list in an automated way?

I am already using `$$PLSQL_UNIT` to get my procedure name.